# Why does this function count the number of set bits in an integer

Tags: c, bit

I was asked the following question in an interview:

```
int foofoo(unsigned int u) {
    unsigned int foo = u;
    do{
        u = u/2;
        foo -= u;
    }while(u > 0);
    return foo;
}
```

I was asked to tell what does this function do and I was able to find that it counts the number of set bits in an unsigned int value, but I was not able to prove that, maybe someone can?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: it's an interview question — analyze this code and tell me what it does.  I'm not sure it is a good interview question, but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand that part sir, The point I am trying to make is, we can have expressions and statements with defined actions/explanations. Putting them together and then trying to find out the purpose... does not make any sense to me. Be it interview question or a question in SO.

Comment: `Why does this function does X...`...umm, probably because someone wrote it to do so?

Comment: Remember `u = u /  2` effectively is a *right shift* of `u`.

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to find that it counts the number of set bits in an unsigned int value, but I was not able to prove that, maybe someone can?

Look at a **single** bit `m`inside `U`. That bit contributes to the value of `U` like:

U = ...... + U<sub>m</sub> 2^m + ..... (where the .... represents other bits).

In each loop the bit is divived by 2 and then subtracted from `U`. When the loop is complete, this looks like the line below for bit `m`:

U<sub>m</sub> 2^m - U<sub>m</sub> 2^(m-1) - U<sub>m</sub> 2^(m-2) - .... - U<sub>m</sub> 2^0

This can be rewritten like:

U<sub>m</sub> (2^m - (2^(m-1) + 2^(m-2) + .... + 2^0))

U<sub>m</sub> (2^m - (2^m -1))

U<sub>m</sub> (2^m - 2^m + 1)

U<sub>m</sub>

So from this we can see, that bit `m` contributes to the final result with its bit-value (i.e. 0 or 1). This, of cause, holds true for all bit in `U`. Therefore:

`foo` = U<sub>n-1</sub> + U<sub>n-2</sub> + ... + U<sub>m</sub> + ... + U<sub>1</sub> + U<sub>0</sub>

Consequently, the result will be equal to the number of bits set in `U`.

p.s. I tried to use superscript to make the formulas look better. But I couldn't make `<sup>` work. Feel free to edit the formulas if you know how.

Answer (score 1):

## The Idea

[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_counting) that an unsigned integer `u` can be represented as a sum of powers of two:

```
u = A * 2ª + ... + N * 2ⁿ,
```

where `0 <= a < ... < n` are integers, and `A, ..., N` are either zeroes, or
ones. If we remove the zero-product terms, the number of terms will be equal
to the number of set bits (ones). For example, `1101`<sub>**b**</sub> = 2⁰ +
2² + 2³ consists of three terms (powers of two), and the number of set bits is also equal to three.

The idea is to find *the number of non-zero terms* in this representation.

## Algorithm

If we express `u` as a sum of powers of two:

```
u = 2ª + ... + 2ⁿ
```

where `0 <= a < ... < n`, then the integer division `u = u / 2` can be expressed as:

```
u = ( 2ª + ... + 2ⁿ ) / 2
```

or, equivalently:

```
u = ( 2ª / 2 ) + ... + ( 2ⁿ / 2 )
```

(Since, generally, `(x + y) / 2 = (x / 2) + (y / 2)`.)

The process is repeated while `u` is positive. So each term eventually becomes equal to *one*. In the next iteration it *becomes equal to zero due to the rules of integer division*: `1 / 2 = 0`.

The resulting value (`u`) is subtracted from the original value stored in `foo`: `foo -= u`.

Thus, we **eventually subtract everything from the original value `foo`, except the "ones divided by two" (`1 / 2`)**.

Obviously, the number of occurrences of `1 / 2` is equal to the number of non-zero terms in the original expression of `u` which is equal to the number of set bits (as we found out above). Hence, the value remaining ìn `foo` is  a sum of "`1 / 2`" leftovers, i.e. the number of terms which is also the number of set bits.

## Example

Let's visualize the process on example of `u = 13`.

Binary representation of the decimal number `13` is `1101`. So the sum of powers of two in decimal notation is:

```
u = 2⁰ + 2² + 2³
```

First iteration:

```
u = u / 2
  = (2⁰ + 2² + 2³) / 2
  = (2⁰ / 2) + (2² / 2) + (2³ / 2)
  = 0        + 2        + 2²
```

We have one zero so far: `2⁰ / 2 = 1 / 2 = 0`.

Second iteration:

```
u = u / 2
  = (2      + 2²) / 2
  = (2 / 2) + (2² / 2)
  = 1       + 2
```

No more zeroes in this iteration. Third iteration:

```
u = u / 2
  = (1      + 2) / 2
  = (1 / 2) + (2 / 2)
  = 0       + 1
```

We have got the second zero in this iteration: `1 / 2 = 0`.

Fourth iteration gives the third zero:

```
u = u / 2
  = 1 / 2 = 0.
```

The number of zeroes is equal to the number of set bits, i.e. `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose when the input is `N`, the output is `M`. Then when the input is `2*N` the output is still `M`, and when the input is `2*N+1` the output must be `M+1` (both statements follow from the analysis of the first iteration of the loop which reduces the input to `N`).